# How can I contact FLSUN support?

Tags: flsun

If I have an issue with my FLSUN printer how can I contact customer support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have a webpage by now   [www.flsun3d.com](http://www.flsun3d.com)

Answer (score 2):

I have had good luck contacting them via AliExpress https://flsun.aliexpress.com/store/2383013 even though I bought my printer on Amazon.